# How can we pass a CSV file using HTTP request methods from an angular application to a node application running on a server

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, multipartform-data, form-data

I have created a front-end application in angular, and using HTTP service methods to send request to a server (containing node.js code). At front-end, I have created a csv file which is saved in the same directory of the angular component. I want to send the file to the server (containing node.js code) using HTTP service methods. I have created following code:

Code of client side (front-end side), developed in angular.js:

```
uploadCSVFileOnServer(){
    let file = new File([""], "./abc.csv"));
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("userForm", file);
    let userData = {
        firstName : "ABC",
        lastName : "DEF",
        userFormData: formData
    }

    this.http.post('url', userData)
    .subscribe(()=>{
        console.log("File uploaded successfully");
    })
}
```

Now `http.post()` methods send request to a method (`getFile()`) written in node.js running on a server. The node.js code (server side code) is as follows:

```
getFile(req, res){
    let file = req.body.userData.userFormData ;
    // PROBLEM: 'file' is an empty object here 
}
```

My doubt is that, from client side I have sent a javascript object which also contains the FormData object (with key `userFormData`). But when I try to fetch the `FormData` object in `getFile()` method at server side , I get an empty object which is also not of type `FormData`.

What is the problem? Is `FormData.append()` not working at client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormData` object is an exotic object that can not be POSTed as a property of a JavaScript object.

Instead append JSON data to the FormData object:

```
uploadCSVFileOnServer(){
    let file = new Blob([""], {type: "application/csv"});
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("csvFile", file, "abc.csv");
    let userData = {
        firstName : "ABC",
        lastName : "DEF",
        //userFormData: formData
    }
    formData.append("userData", JSON.stringify(userData));

    this.http.post('url', formData)
    .subscribe(()=>{
        console.log("FormData uploaded successfully");
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please give me some useful resource from where I could read 'FormData' object concept. I am searching , but not getting any useful resource.

Comment: Read [MDN Web API Reference - FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: I created the code as you suggested. But at server side getting an empty object (not any 'FormData' object)

Comment: The client does not send an object with a FormData POST request, it sends `multipart/form-data`. So it consists of several parts, each with its own header and delimited using a (usually randomly generated) boundary string. The boundary string is given as a parameter to the content type of the whole document, as specified in the HTTP header. The field names are specified using the `content-disposition` header of each part. The `multipart/form-data` type is specified in [RFC 2388](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388).

Comment: `multipart/form-data` provides a more powerful alternative to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type which will by default be used to submit form data in the body of a POST request. **It adds the ability to transfer files,** submit file names and content types for each of these, and also allows for different form fields to use different encodings. The added versatility comes at the cost of more overhead to process and transmit these messages.